# Updating ModelForm Django 1.10

Tags: python, django, social-networking, modelform, updatemodel

I'm fairly new to coding in general, so please forgive my ignorance.

I have a ModelForm (Django 1.10 -just in case-) for a 'post' on a social network website:

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   text = models.TextField()
   image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
   draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   submission_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.text
```

forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Post
         fields = ['text', 'image', 'draft']
```

To update a post, this is its function:
views.py:

```
def edit_post(request, post_id):
  post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)

  if not request.user.is_superuser and\
  not request.user == post.user:
    raise PermissionDenied

  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
    if form.is_valid():
      post = form.save(commit=False)
      post.user = request.user
      post.save()
      context = {'post': post,'form': form}
      return HttpResponse(render(request, 'accounts/view_post.html', context))

   elif request.method == 'GET':
     form = PostForm(request.GET, instance=post)
     context = {'post': post,'form': form}
     return HttpResponse(render(request, 'accounts/edit_post.html', context))
```

in the template:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{% include 'accounts/form_template.html' %}
<input class="btn btn-btn-success" type="submit" value="Save Post">
</form>
```

My question is: when trying to update, why does the original field input not show up? The fields turn up empty as if I were creating a new post.

The more detailed answer, the more I would appreciate it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does form_template.html look like?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I just realised I forgot about form_template.html

{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group" style="padding-up: 10px">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ field.label_tag}}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">{{ field }}<br><br></div>
    </div>

{% endfor %}

Sorry about that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was remove 'request.GET':
in views.py:

```
def edit_post(request, post_id):
     post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
     ...
     ...
    elif request.method == 'GET':
         form = PostForm(instance=post)

         context = {'post': post,
                    'form': form}
         return HttpResponse(render(request, 'accounts/edit_post.html', context))
```

Thank you to everyone who tried to help, especially @Zagorodniy Olexiy.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show original inputs in the form you have to ad some code in your `PostForm`:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ['text', 'image', 'draft']

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for key in self.fields:
      self.fields[key].required = False
```

then you have to load it in to the view

```
def edit_post(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    if not request.user.is_superuser and\
    not request.user == post.user:
        raise PermissionDenied

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            context = {'post': post,
                       'form': form}
            return HttpResponse(render(request, 'accounts/view_post.html', context))

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form = PostForm(request.GET, instance=post)

        context = {'post': post,
                   'form': form}
        return HttpResponse(render(request, 'accounts/edit_post.html', context))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could I just ask: what is ExtraProfileDataForm?

Comment: @ Zagorodniy Olexiy, no problem, but it's still not working. Someone told me that I was not passing the request.GET correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: I added the code for my Post model. By the way, thanks for your efforts.